# Salesforce - Hide/ show list view button based on profile

Tags: case, custom-button, list-view, lightninglistview

I have a custom 'Create Case' button added in the list view buttons for my custom Case object. For admin profiles I want to show the standard 'New' button and the custom 'Create Case' button to create a new case. For every other profile I want them to create a new case using the custom 'Create Case' button. How do I hide the standard 'New' button in the list view buttons options only for specific profiles? Is this possible?

[image]

Here, I want non admin profiles to see only Import, Change owner and Create Case button. Not the New one.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to create a separate layout for your specific profiles, then click the wrench icon for the Case related list, click the Buttons banner at the bottom, and then you can disable the standard New button.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I need this in the record list view page, not on a related list. I have updated the question with a screenshot for you reference. Is it possible in list view ?